# "package identifier or launch activity not found" in Flutter app using Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I recently updated my Android SDK, and my version of Flutter.

When I tried to test my app after the update, I receive this error:

package identifier or launch activity not found.
Please check C:\Users\matta\StudioProjects\smile-app-master\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml for errors.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_x86.
Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.

When I look at my AndroidManifest, there are several errors that were not there before the update:

Attribute android:icon is not allowed here
Unresolved class 'MainActivity'
Attribute android:launchMode is not allowed here
Attribute android:theme is not allowed here
Attribute android:configChanges is not allowed here
Attribute android:hardwareAccelerated is not allowed here
Attribute android:windowSoftInputMode is not allowed here

I have tried the fixes I have seen online (e.g., Invalidate Caches, close the AndroidManifest and reopen it, etc.), but none seems to fix the problem.